# Power Bi creating monthly measure from repeated monhts

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I have an application database that is designed the following way: (I cannot change it)

I need to be able to create a cash flow that can tell me by month, Property and type what the amount of that month is. I figured I need in a measure in a table that has all the months I need, but I am not sure how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it!

[Link to screenshot, it wont let me post it directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E8qX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Even with the screenshot, it is not entirely clear to me what is meant by repeated month. I am assuming that if repeat_count = 2 and amount = 100 then amount_wanted = 200.
I am also assuming that you already loaded the data into Power BI.
In that case you need to perform the following steps:

1. Create a calculated column holding the month. You can do so using the function month(date).
2. Create a calculated column as 
   amount_wanted = [repeat_count] * [amount]
3. Create a new measure: 
   new_measure = sum([amount_wanted])
4. Create a matrix visual with property and type in the rows, month in the columns and new_measure in the values.

Comment: Sorry that I did not explain myself well enough, and thank you for your answer.

If repeat count is 5 in the month of January and amount 100, then I need it to show that for the next 5 months the amount is 100, and then always after that comes the next value. So continuing the example, it would say June 105 repeat 2 months. The values I need would then be  (January 100, Feb 100, Mar 100, Apr 100, May 100, June 105, July 105)

Hope that helps!